# Array as value in ValueSet

Tags: c++, arrays, c++-winrt

My goal is to add array of strings as value into `ValueSet`. I can do it in `C#`  without any problem, but facing some problems in `C++-WinRT`.

I am trying to pass `array_view` to `box_value` in order to convert it to `IInspectable` type, but getting error `T must be WinRT type`. Here is sample code to check the problem:

```
ValueSet MyValueSet;
hstring key(L"key");
vector<wstring> mystringvalues{ L"1",L"2" };
std::vector<hstring> hvector;
for (std::wstring v : mystringvalues) {
    hvector.push_back(hstring(v));
}
array_view<hstring> hvalue(hvector);
IInspectable keyValue = box_value(hvalue);
MyValueSet.Insert(key, keyValue);
```

Please advise how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/collections on how to create Collection objects.

This code should work:

```
ValueSet myValueSet;
hstring key(L"key");
std::vector<std::wstring> mystringvalues{ L"1",L"2" };
std::vector<hstring> hvector;
for (std::wstring v : mystringvalues) {
    hvector.push_back(hstring(v));
}
myValueSet.Insert(key, winrt::single_threaded_vector(std::move(hvector)));
```

or even shorter:

```
ValueSet myValueSet;
myValueSet.Insert(L"key", winrt::single_threaded_vector<hstring>({L"1", L"2"}));
```

Answer (score 0):

`winrt::single_threaded_vector<hstring>` doesn't work for me.

I found the method PropertyValue.CreateStringArray(String[]) work fine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.propertyvalue.createstringarray

set value:

```
ValueSet MyValueSet;
hstring key(L"key");
vector<wstring> mystringvalues{ L"1",L"2" };
std::vector<hstring> hvector;
for (std::wstring v : mystringvalues) {
    hvector.push_back(hstring(v));
}
array_view<hstring> hvalue(hvector);
MyValueSet.Insert(key, PropertyValue::CreateStringArray(hvalue));
```

or

```
MyValueSet.Insert(key, PropertyValue::CreateStringArray(com_array<hstring>{ L"1", L"2" }));
```

and get value:

```
com_array<hstring> strValues = MyValueSet.Lookup(key).as<IReferenceArray<hstring>>().Value();
for (hstring str : strValues)
{
    wcout << L"str = " << str.c_str() << endl;
}
```